# WiFi Connected Android Phone to Watch Emulator over ADB

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, wear-os

I've started using [adb over WiFi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless) but am having trouble now connecting my phone to an Android watch emulator.

When [pairing a usb-connected phone to a watch emulator](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#pair-phone-with-avd) I need to do some port forwarding between the emulator and the phone:

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

How can I do this forwarding between a wifi-connected phone and a watch emulator?

Below is a list of the devices:

```
~ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
192.168.0.100:5555  device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which device you want to forward to by using the [`-s` option](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#directingcommands):

```
adb -s 192.168.0.100:5555 forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```